# Delete multiple XML attributes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to unite the following statements:

```
UPDATE @Test
SET [XML].modify('delete (Settings/@attributefordeletion1)[1]')

UPDATE @Test
SET [XML].modify('delete (Settings/@attributefordeletion2)[1]')

UPDATE @Test
SET [XML].modify('delete (Settings/@attributefordeletion3)[1]')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
update @Test
set [XML].modify('delete (
                         Settings/@attributefordeletion1, 
                         Settings/@attributefordeletion2, 
                         Settings/@attributefordeletion3
                         )')
```

Or if you want to delete all attributes

```sql
update @Test
set [XML].modify('delete Settings/@*')
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out one more way to delete set of attributes:

```
update @Test
set [XML].modify('delete Settings/@*[local-name()=(
                                    "attributefordeletion1",
                                    "attributefordeletion2", 
                                    "attributefordeletion3"
                                    ]')
```